# replace word that has $ in by sed

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I have some c++ code and i am implementing automization. The code looks like :

```
startTime  0
endTime    10
```

I want to replace `endTime  10` with `endTime  $startTime+10`

I am following this approach, (it is the second occurrence that's why 1,)

```
sed -i "1,/endTime/ s/endTime.*/endTime       $startTime+10;/g" $file_path
```

expexted output:

```
startTime    0
endTime      $startTime+10
```

Thanks.

Comment: Use single quotes, not double quotes.

Comment: Thanks. It worked !